# Is it possible to find an asymptotic distribution for the likelihood ratio test without the maximum likelihood estimators being consistent?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

The usual proofs of the asymptotic distribution of the likelihood ratio test (LRT) being a chi-squared assume that the maximum likelihood (ML) estimators are consistent. Is it possible to find an asymptotic distribution for the LRT without the ML estimators being consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistency means that the MLEs converge *in probability* to the true parameter. Therefore, there are at least two senses in which this can fail.

1. It does not converge: Think sample mean of a Cauchy random variable.
2. Is converges to something else (i.e., it has asymptotic bias)

These are very different cases, so any theorem on the convergence of the LRT needs to add some definite structure. In the case of (1), you are out of luck. For (2) you can correct for bias and then you're back to the consistent case.

**Response to OP Comment**

First, this paper is not directly related to your question: It concerns the *quasi*-loglikelihood, not the log-likelihood, and it pertains to a test of hypothesis, not an estimator.

However, I think I see what your concern is, so I will try to add some of my thoughts to clarify what was said in that paragraph.

The consistency of a hypothesis test is different from the consistency of an estimator, although the two are related. For a hypothesis test to be consistent, the probability of a Type I or Type II error should go to 0 as $n \to \infty$ . This places much weaker constraints on the behavior of your test statistic under the alternative hypothesis. As long as the test statistic converges to a point outside the rejection region when the null if false (again as $n \to \infty$) then the test will correctly reject the null hypothesis in an asymptotic sense. As the authors note, the main effect of an inconsistent test statistics under the alternative hypothesis is a extra layer of uncertainty regarding the power of the test.

However, the Type I error probability is still known and is usually the main focus of a hypothesis test (sample size calculations should be addressed by direct simulation if possible).

This is the gist of that paragraph, the authors are pointing out that the hypothesis test is still valid even though the assumptions for the consistency of the estimator underlying the test are violated. This is due to the forgiving nature of hypothesis tests: they are binary/decision theoretic procedures that only require that you can identify when an outcome is rare, under the null hypothesis.

Comment: Could you then explain the last paragraph of page 3 of this comment to a paper?
http://econ.ucsb.edu/~doug/researchpapers/Testing%20for%20Regime%20Switching%20A%20Comment.pdf

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I've added some thoughts.

Comment: hI've just seen your thoughts. I Haven't had the time to read carefully. In two days, I'll give some feedback.

Until then,+1 and many thanks for your interest in this question, and for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks for the inputs. 
What would change in our reasoning if we considered Loglikelihoods and Quasi-loglikelihoods separately? I'm more interested in the 'quasi' setting.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. well, first of all, its the loglikelihood ratio that has a chi-square, not the actual likelihood ratio, so we really need to just focus on quasi-likelihood. If you look up a quasi likelihood you'll see that it is only a semiparametric model, and any inference relies on asymptotic normality so we're back to the regular likelihood case. therefore, it doesn't change the basic "logic" about consistency. If the estimator converges in probability to *something* then you've got a chot at an asymptotic dist, otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: understood, I think... ;)